# Rails/SQL - How to search for partial match and get results?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is the code for the location search field of a real estate search site:

```
   scope :location, lambda{|l|  where("city LIKE ? OR zip_code LIKE ? OR address LIKE ?", l, l, l)}
```

But I have to put the complete city name or zip code or address to get results, how do I fix it so that I can search for just 2 or 3 letters or numbers and get results that contain those letters or numbers? I tried wrapping the l like this: '%l%' but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :location, lambda{|l|  where("city LIKE :l OR zip_code LIKE :l OR address LIKE :l", l: "%#{l}%")}
```

Comment: @railsy, by the way, the name of your scope doesn't look decent. Isn't it be more descriptive to name it `with_location`? Time files and in a few months you may be confused with `location`.